# why do this error usually occur? System.InvalidOperationException: 'Stack empty.'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, vb.net-2010

I am using a pre defined stack in my vb.net code and I am pushing to it in a specific sub and in another sub I am reading the peek() and inserting it to database but when I click insert it says stack empty.

```
Dim s1 As Stack = New Stack()
Dim s2 As Stack = New Stack()
 Protected Sub check(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim Stri As String = "Data Source=SAYMIX\SAMI_SQL_SERVER;Initial Catalog=TES1;Integrated Security=True"
    con = New SqlConnection(Stri)
    con.Open()
    Dim cmdqid As New SqlCommand
    Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = CType(sender, RadioButtonList)
    For Each rb As ListItem In rbl.Items
        If rb.Selected = True Then
            Session("rbtext") = rb.Text
            Session("value") = rb.Value

            cmdqid = New SqlCommand("SELECT quest.qid FROM quest WHERE quest.qdesc LIKE '" & Session("rbtext") & "' ", con)
            Dim qid As Int16 = cmdqid.ExecuteScalar()

            Session("qid") = qid
            s2.Push(Session("qid"))
            s1.Push(Session("value"))
            con.Close()
        End If
    Next

End Sub
Protected Sub insertbtn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim Stri As String = "Data Source=SAYMIX\SAMI_SQL_SERVER;Initial Catalog=TES1;Integrated Security=True"
    con = New SqlConnection(Stri)
    con.Open()
    Dim ins As New SqlCommand
    Dim cmdcritid As New SqlCommand
    Dim cmdqid As New SqlCommand
    cmdqid = New SqlCommand("SELECT quest.qid FROM quest WHERE quest.qdesc LIKE '" & Session("rbtext") & "' ", con)
    Dim qid As Int16 = cmdqid.ExecuteScalar()
    cmdcritid = New SqlCommand("SELECT quest.critid FROM quest WHERE quest.qid= '" & qid & "' ", con)
    Dim critid As Int16 = cmdcritid.ExecuteScalar()
    ins = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [result](quid,did,critid,qid,pid,qvalue) values('" & DropDownList1.SelectedValue & "','" & DropDownList3.SelectedValue & "','" & critid & "','" & s2.Peek() & "','" & DropDownList2.SelectedValue & "','" & s1.Peek() & "')", con)
    ins.ExecuteScalar()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: If you get a message that tells you that the stack is empty then I think it's fair to say that the stack is empty. Why are you looking for a different explanation? I think that you probably need to debug your code.

Comment: but i filled it why would it say this.

Comment: We all think that we have done something when we haven't at various times. That's why VS has a debugger. The IDE would not be telling you that the stack was empty if it wasn't so clearly you think you have done something that you haven't or you have done something that you have. Use the debugger to find out what you've done wrong. I shouldn't need to tell you that once, never mind twice. If you don't know how to debug then stop what you're doing and learn that first, then do it. If this is a Web Forms app, which it appears to be, then I it may be because you're adding items before a postback.